# Is there a way to make an animated scroll up transition between two different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I am currently designing a website in which I have a first page that shows a language selector, which should take you to the corresponding version of the homepage depending on the chosen language. I would like to animate the transition between these pages so that the 'language selector' page scrolls up and gives way to the appropriate 'homepage'.

I am really new to coding, but I can understand the very basics of jQuery and got some jQuery-based solutions to work, though I haven't succeeded yet in finding a method that fits what I want.

If you have a look at my working website, http://bauti.tk, you'll see the 'language selector' page has a black background. I would like to join that as seamlessly as possible with the black menu bar on top of the 'homepage' as it scrolls.

The way the contents other than the menu in the 'homepage' load is not really important for me. I've seen many solutions based on scrolling through sections of a same webpage, but I guess that won't work for me, as the target webpage depends on the language choice.

Any working solutions are welcome, regardless of their difficulty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into ajax for this solution. Basically load the selected language homepage underneath the landing page upon selection, then scroll down to reveal the loaded content.

Something like:

```
var lang;
$(".ThumbGroup span").find("a").off("click","a").on({
    click: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(($(this).attr("id") == "u2008-4") || ($(this).attr("id") == "u2003")){
            lang = "cat-home.html"
        }else if($(this).attr("id") == "u2009"){
            lang = "en-home.html";
        }else if($(this).attr("id") == "u2005"){
            lang = "zh-home.html";
        }

        $.get({"http://bauti.tk/"+lang, function(data) {
            $("#page").append(data);

            //Add scroll effect here using .scroll() method.
            //https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

        });
    }
},"a");
```

There's some customizing you'll have to do with this code but it could serve as a boilerplate for you.

Keep in mind, however, when using ajax the url will not actually change when you click the links unless you put the necessary code in place to change it.